# HTML DIV to excel conversion framework

Tags: html, excel, jakarta-ee

All,
is there a tool library/framework like ZK to convert an existing HTML  or HTML div area to excel.

My HTML DIV element is a complex element with images and row and column structures. Is there a solution that makes it easy to convert such DIV elements created dynamically?

My web application is a j2ee application on websphere AS and uses Sprin3+Struts 2.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered examining it, using regex to convert it to a CSV, then importing the CSV to excel?

Comment: My Div contains images and merged rows/columns etc. Not sure if csv can handle that.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that you've got divs. From what I know of Excel, the file types are marked up with a form of modified XML. As such, you can take the page (assuming you have all associated files linked with absolute paths) and change the extension to XLS. It'll open. Your formatting may be extremely screwy, though, because you're using divs and likely CSS positions.

Comment: Adding my approach so that it might help others: I used jxls to first do the data transformation, from my existing objects and then in phase 2, I used apache POI so that I can embed image where required. this was a 2 phase transformation. JXLS was easy but embedding image was tough. Used apache POI tutorials to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered exporting your data from Java using Apache POI library?
http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: yes, I have. The problem is POI is very basic considering amount of complex structure my HTML section will have. If there is some framework/library like ZK for this job, I can leverage the availability of my DTO objects and the HTML representation to create the XLS. In POI I will have to to a cell by cell copy of data. Does POI also provide the option to embed images in specific cells?

Comment: I added my approach to the question as comments. Thanks for helping.